# Roaming Profile Permissions and Migration

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, roaming-profile, robocopy

Currently a client as 2003 DC and we are migrating them to a 2008R2 on a 2012 Hyper-V Host. They have a handful of roaming profiles - but with the usual setup - i.e. the only permissions on the actual roaming profile folders i.e. username.v2 are SYSTEM (full control) and the actual user (Full control) - I had to take ownership as an admin to actually see these permissions. Basically as per:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737633(WS.10).aspx

How can I migrate these across as I have no permissions over them as administrator, can I just do a straight robocopy and then re-point the Profile location attribute in AD to the new location? (obviously configuring share permissions on folder on new server)

Comment: What client systems are using the roaming profiles and are the client systems changing? XP/2003 profiles are not compatible with nor will they interoperate with Vista/7/2K8/2K8R2 profiles.

Comment: Client Systems will not change - client systems are currently a mix of Windows XP and Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I got round this with [PSEXEC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

On the server that currently stores your profiles bring up an administrative command prompt and run

```
PSEXEC /S "CMD.EXE"
```

This gets you into Session 0, effectively running as the local system account, at which point you have the ability to do what you wish with these accounts. I chose to use XCOPY

Xcopy *.* \newserver\share\ /E /I

You can use the /X switch to preserve the permissions. I chose to leave that off and separately script the permissions to allow access for server admins without having to mess about elevating Explorer or using explorer alternatives.

Once the profiles are across then its just a case of, as you say, pointing AD profiles at the new share\folder.

Comment: Good catch for the psexec as session 0. As you have to usually apply a gpo setting that add admin account to the security of the roaming profile for administration (like backup), but it only apply at the profile creation.

Answer (score 0):

I did a migration like this during the logon of the user. Don't forget that you want to migrate the registry keys as well as the files. For that you can use the procedure in this blogpost. http://blog.raido.be/?p=297 (it talks about AppSense, but this will work without AppSense also. just use the copy command and the reg.exe command during user logon.